# VS Code Find and Replace across files using Regex to correct error in number of quotes appearing on a particular line

Tags: html, regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

**EDIT:**
While @Wiktor Stribiżew's answer helped me resolve both my issues (thanks again!), I came across a 3rd issue, on the lines of the 2nd one.

Error:

```
"Image" : "'Motorola_About'
```

There is an unwanted single quote before the 'Motorola_About' thread and the closing quote needs to changed to double. There is white-space before and after the colon (:) which needs to be retained.

I tried the below codes on the lines of the answer given for the previous issue
FIND:

```
(" : ")"([^']*_About[^']")
```

```
("/s:/s")"([^']*_About[^']")
```

REPLACE:

```
$1$2
```

Both approaches did not work. Would appreciate any help or assistance in telling me where I'm going wrong.

**TRAIL:**
I am trying to use VS Code's (Ver 1.55.2) 'Replace in Files' to correct an error in number of quotes appearing on a particular line across multiple files.
In both the error cases, there is an additional single quote (') that has appeared in the same position (before the image name) in error, which I need to remove across all the files.

Error type 1:

```
html file1 Line 50: 'ImageName':''Microsoft_About',
html file2 Line 51: 'ImageName':''Motorola_About',
html file3 Line 53: 'ImageName':''Apple_About',
```

..and so on across 450 odd files

Error type 2:

```
html file9 Line 50: "ImageName":"'Microsoft_About",
html file12 Line 51: "ImageName":"'Motorola_About",
html file15 Line 53: "ImageName":"'Apple_About",
```

..and so on across another 350 odd files

I tried using the following Regex code in 'Replace in Files':
For Error1:

```
FIND: ([''])([a-zA-Z0-9,.-]+_)(_About')
REPLACE: $2_About'
```

For Error2:

```
FIND: (["'])([a-zA-Z0-9,.-]+_)(_About')
REPLACE: $2_About'
```

It is not working. I'm new to Regex and not familiar with the codes, so would highly appreciate any help and advice with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first set of files you can use

*Find*: `'('[^']*)(_About')`
*Replace*: `$1$2`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3fmsWs/2/). For the second one, you may use

*Find*: `(":")'([^"]*_About")` 
*Replace*: `$1$2`

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3fmsWs/3/).

*Details*:

- `'('[^']*)(_About')` - a `'` is matched, then a `'` and zero or more chars other than `'` are captured into Group 1 (`$1`) and then `_About'` is captured into Group 2 (`$2`).
- `(":")'([^"]*_About")` - `":"` is first captured into Group 1 (`$1`), then a `'` is matched, and then any zero or more chars other than `"` and `_About"` is captured into Group 2.

The matches are replaced with appropriate group value(s).

Comment: Hi @Wiktor. Thanks for the very helpful reply. It helped me resolve both those errors. But I realized I also have a 3rd error coming to my notice. In this case, it is like the second one but there is space before and after the colon and the closing quote is single instead of double. `"Image" : "'Motorola_About'`. I want to retain the space but change the closing quote to a double quote. I tried resolving it by modifying your code slightly `(" : ")'([^"]*_About[^']")` and replacing with `$1$2`but it doesn't work. Could you help?

Comment: @MithunUchil You can use `(" : ")'([^"]*_About[^']*)'` and replace with `$1$2"`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3fmsWs/4).

Answer (score 0):

I used one regex to match both cases with the same replace statements. [`Regex Explanation`](http://regexr.com/5qu6f)

```js
const regex = /('|")(.*?)(?:'|"):(?:'|")+(.*?)(?:'|")/;

const error1 = [`'ImageName':''Apple_About'`, `'ImageName':''Motorola_About'`, `'ImageName':''Microsoft_About'`];
const error2 = [`"ImageName":"'Microsoft_About"`,`"ImageName":"'Motorola_About"`, `"ImageName":"'Apple_About"`];

console.log(error1.map(err => err.replace(regex, '$1$2$1:$1$3$1')));
console.log(error2.map(err => err.replace(regex, '$1$2$1:$1$3$1')));
```

Comment: Hi @a.mola. Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry, but could you help me with how I need to use this in the "Find in Files" and "Replace in Files" boxes?? Very, very sorry, maybe I wasn't clear in my query, but each line belongs to a separate html file. And I need the 'Find-replace' to target only that specific line across multiple files.

Comment: Well, I don't think there's a way to select a particular line of a file, but the regex should find this kind of an error. Then the line numbers are shown as well, so you can remove the lines you don't want to change. [Read more] here(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_search-across-files)

Comment: Put the `regex` in the `find` box and the `$1$2$1:$1$3$1` in the replace box